# How to detect that the server socket is closed in a callback in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Is there any method or property that I could use for the server socket to detect that it has been closed?
I have a main loop (running on a separate thread) where my server is accepting (using BeginAccept) connections from clients and processes the acceptance in the call-back method asynchronously:

```
while (!terminate)
{
   // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
   acceptedConnectionFromControllerDone.Reset();

   listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
   // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
   acceptedConnectionFromControllerDone.WaitOne();
}
```

When I close my server app (the "Form" in my case) I set the flag for my main loop (from FormClosing handler) to terminate the main loop, which in turn closes the server socket (using Close method). When that happens the 'AcceptCallback' call-back is processing a new client acceptance and when it calls EndAccept on server socket it throws an exception that the object has been disposed. How can I detect in the call-back that the socket has been closed using server socket object? I know that I could create internal flag that is set to true when I close the socket in main loop (or catch an exception), but is there more elegant solution then that?
I am asking for the server socket solution but this is actually a generic question for any callbacks of either client or server socket – how to handle socket closed in the asynchronous callback?

Comment: It's a good question and it shows a design defect in `Socket`. The closed socket should be detected and handled gracefully by the `EndXXX()` call since the client code cannot do so cleanly. Even if there were a way of querying the closed/partially disposed state of the socket, the closing could happen between querying the state and calling `EndXXX()`. The best you can do is set a flag before closing the socket and not call `EndXXX()` if the flag is set, hoping that the socket will clean up any leftovers. Or do the call and ignore the resulting `ObjectDisposedException` if your flag is set.